Is this "binary submatrix sum equation" problem NP-hard?
There is an unknown matrix $A$ of $R$ rows and $C$ columns. The entry at the $r$-th row, $c$-th column is $A_{rc}$. The matrix is a binary matrix, i.e. each entry is either 0 or 1.
Another matrix $B$ of $R-1$ rows and $C-1$ columns is given. Each entry of $B$ indicates the sum of entries in each $2 \times 2$ submatrix of $A$; precisely, $B_{rc} = \sum_{i=r}^{r+1} \sum_{j=c}^{c+1} A_{ij}$. The problem is to determine if a matrix $A$ exists whose "submatrix sum" is $B$.
Is this problem NP-hard?
Context: I'm trying to solve a perfect-information, consistency version of Minesweeper. That is, the problem of locating all mines when the number of mines in the 3x3 region around every cell is known, or determining that it is impossible. When both $R$ and $C$ are 2 modulo 3, the system of equations essentially turns into the problem above, where each cell of $A$ represents each Minesweeper cell whose row and column numbers are not multiples of 3.

Does this help? https://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/minesw/ordmsw.htm

Do you have an instance where the LP relaxation (a ∈ [0,1] instead of a ∈ {0,1}) has a solution but doesn't have an integer solution? I couldn't find one.

Not sure if this helps, but if the problem was submatrix XOR, then there will always exist $2^{R+C-1}$ and its easy to construct any one of them in $\mathcal{O}(RC)$ operations.

@codeR I'm aware of it, but the gadgets used to prove NP-hardness make use of "known-mine" cells that do not give its surrounding mine count, so it doesn't apply here.

TLDR
Showed the problem is solvable in polynomial $\mathcal{O}(RC)$ time using 2-SAT on variables $$\boldsymbol{x} = [ A_{1, 2}, A_{1, 3},  \dots A_{1, C}, A_{2, 1}, A_{3, 1}, \dots A_{R, 1}]$$

First I augment $B$ with one more row and column from the front, so that what was $B_{i, j}$ initially becomes $B'_{i+1, j+1}$ in the new matrix $B'$. This matrix $B'$ has $R+C-1$ variables in the form of $$\boldsymbol{x} = [B'_{1, 1}, B'_{1, 2}, \dots B'_{1, C}, B'_{2, 1}, B'_{3, 1}, \dots B'_{R, 1}]$$
I form matrix $A$ using this matrix $B'$ by the recursion $$A_{i,j} = \begin{cases}
B'_{1,1} & \text{ if } i=1 \land j=1 \\
B'_{1,j} - A_{1, j-1} & \text{ otherwise if } i=1 \\
B'_{i,1} - A_{i-1, 1} & \text{ otherwise if } j=1 \\
B'_{i, j} - A_{i-1, j} - A_{i, j-1} - A_{i-1, j-1} & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Now the coefficient of $B'_{x, y}$ in $A_{i, j}$ will be $0$ if $i<x$ or $j<y$, and $(-1)^{(i-x)+(j-y)}$ otherwise. This can be shown via inclusion-exclusion or induction. So $$\begin{split}
A_{i,j} &= \sum_{x=1}^{i} \sum_{y=1}^{j} (-1)^{(i-x)+(j-y)} B'_{x, y} \\
&= (-1)^{i+j} \sum_{x=1}^{i} \sum_{y=1}^{j} (-1)^{x+y} B'_{x, y} \\
\end{split}$$
Let $B''_{x, y} = (-1)^{x+y} B'_{x, y}$, then $$\begin{split}
A_{i,j} &= (-1)^{i+j} \sum_{x=1}^{i} \sum_{y=1}^{j} B''_{x, y} \\
&= (-1)^{i+j} \left( \sum_{x=2}^{i} \sum_{y=2}^{j} B''_{x, y} + \sum_{x=1}^{i} B''_{x, 1} + \sum_{y=1}^{j} B''_{1, y} -  B''_{1, 1} \right) \\
&= (-1)^{i+j} \left( \sum_{x=2}^{i} \sum_{y=2}^{j} B''_{x, y} + (-1)^{i+1} A_{i, 1} + (-1)^{j+1} A_{1, j} -  A_{1, 1} \right) \\
\end{split}$$
Let $B'''_{i, j} = (-1)^{i+j} \sum_{x=2}^{i} \sum_{y=2}^{j} B''_{x, y}$, then $$
A_{i,j} =  B'''_{i, j} - \left( (-1)^{j} A_{i, 1} + (-1)^{i} A_{1, j} + (-1)^{i+j}  A_{1, 1} \right)
$$
For all $i, j\ge 2$, where $B'''_{i, j}$ can be easily calculated from the initial matrix $B$ (without any variables) . Now the only constraint which should be satisfied is either $A_{i, j} = 0$ or $A_{i, j} = 1$.
Now we can go into both cases $A_{1,1} = 0$ and $A_{1, 1} = 1$ and solve for the rest of the variables $$\boldsymbol{x} = [ A_{1, 2}, A_{1, 3},  \dots A_{1, C}, A_{2, 1}, A_{3, 1}, \dots A_{R, 1}]$$ via creating a satisifiability problem on these constraints. Giving an example on how to convert a constraint to a satisifiability expression:
Lets take $i$ even, $j$ odd, $A_{1, 1} = 1$, $A_{1, j} = x$ and $A_{i, 1}=y$. Then the above constraint can be written in the form that $B'''_{i, j} - \left( - y +  x + -1 \right) = $ $(B'''_{i, j} + 1) + (y-x)$is either $0$ or $1$. That automatically gives us the constraint that $(B'''_{i, j} + 1)$ can only be $-1$, $0$, $1$ or $2$, otherwise this case for $A_{1,1} =1$ is not feasible.
Here if this value is $-1$ or $2$ (corner cases), then the constraint can be written in a 1-SAT expression $ (y\land\neg x)$ or $ (\neg y\land x)$ respectively. This cases are easy to handle as they solidify some variables for the rest of the problem.
And for the values of $0$ or $1$ (middle cases) we get 2-SAT expressions $(y \lor \neg x)$ or $(\neg y \lor x)$. This cases can be collected and solved together using the 2-SAT solution in polynomial time.
This analysis for was a certain example, but (if I am not missing anything) all possible constraints will fall under the same situations as above (either its infeasible, or a 1-SAT, or a 2-SAT) giving us a polynomial time algorithm for the problem.
